# How to get sum of n cell above using ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I want to calculate Relative Strength Index that use the sum of 14 day of Gains.
I can use SUM function then drag down to the bottom, but I want it to expand infinitely (H16 to H).
Is there any way to use ARRAYFORMULA? or I must use appscript?
I try many things and can't figure the way out.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have a blank Row 2? Is it necessary? You can also help us help you by sharing a link to a sample spreadsheet containing realistic data in Col A; otherwise the volunteer contributors here would have to start a new sheet and enter sufficient data themselves before they can even begin to think about a solution (and that will be a deterrent to many).

Comment: sure, here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1exIW0rI-yD6GLVbrPeZhrU4odx4jsFcDp32qDJsiYzY/edit data is in BTC sheet.

Comment: Before other volunteer contributors here decide whether or not to jump in, please review the solution offered by player0 and either accept that answer or comment on that post as to why it does not meet your needs. It is also unclear on your shared spreadsheet where you would be wanting to see the formula in question, as the setup of none of the columns with "RSI" in the header match your posted example.

Comment: There are solutions that do not use MMULT at all, but you still have not responded to my question from my first comment above: "Why do you have a blank Row 2? Is it necessary?"

Comment: It has blank because Gain is calculate by close price of current row cell minus above cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(G3:G))<14,,
 MMULT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(G3:G)-SEQUENCE(1, 14, 0),
 {ROW(G3:G), G3:G}, 2, )*1, 0), SEQUENCE(14, 1, 1, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: thank for anwser, but this still have same problem, work only with small data. Instead of error this frozen my PC. I do some research and google sheet is not suit for my work, so I moved to python. Thank for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(SEQUENCE(MATCH(9, 1/(G3:G<>"")))<16,,
 MMULT(N(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(" "&trim(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(
 SEQUENCE(MATCH(9, 1/(G3:G<>"")))>=SEQUENCE(1, MATCH(9, 1/(G3:G<>""))),
 TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("G3:G"&MATCH(9, 1/(G:G<>"")))), )),,9^9))),
 REPT(" -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?", 14)&"$"), " "))), SEQUENCE(14, 1, 1, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late response, I've been busy.
It work perfectly fine for small data, but somehow for large data (I try 9000 data) It give error
"MMULT has incompatible matrix sizes. Number of columns in first matrix (1) must equal number of rows in second matrix (14)."
Or I shouldn't do large calculation like this on google spreadsheet?
Should I do in programming language like python or C instead?